# import image based on vlookup result

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Vlookup set up from a selection in a drop down window. This is easy. What I am finding difficult is once I select a name, I need their image to show up in an area of my worksheet. Any help would be appreciated. I am using Excel 2010. Thank you.

Comment: Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEM0pp5SjMU), is that what you're looking to do?  Or [this thread](http://trumpexcel.com/2013/11/picture-lookup-in-excel-using-named-ranges/)?

Comment: That is a way to do it if the images are in the same workbook. I have the pictures in another folder under their respective names but not in a workbook. I was looking to linking that folder somehow to this worksheet. My first thought was a hyperlink but I am stuck.

Comment: Any reason you can't just copy them into the workbook on some helper sheet (ie "Images") and then pull from there? Or are you trying to pull the images from a network location or folder (i.e. C:\Users\Me\Pictures\myImage.jpg)?

Comment: Yes the pictures are on a network drive. I thought it might be easier to do it this way but I might have to copy and paste each picture into the workbook somewhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a picture into your worksheet in the location that you want then you can just use that pictures properties to insert a new picture (after deleting the old one). Alternatively, you could set the size properties as constants. Paste this code into a module:

```
Const PicturePath = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\"
Sub ChangePicture(PictureName)
    Dim p As Picture
    Dim ptop, pleft, pwidth, pheight
    On Error GoTo errorhandler
    For Each p In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        ptop = p.Top
        pleft = p.Left
        pwidth = p.Width
        pheight = p.Height
        p.Delete
    Next p

    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (PicturePath & PictureName)

    For Each p In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        p.Top = ptop
        p.Left = pleft
        p.Width = pwidth
        p.Height = pheight
    Next p
    Exit Sub
 errorhandler:
    MsgBox "Error loading file, check the filename to make sure it is valid.", _
        vbCritical, "ChangePicture"
End Sub
```

then add this code to the worksheet with your picture names

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Value <> "" Then
    ChangePicture Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

In the worksheet, if you have a list of picture names like

```
 Desert.jpg
 Jellyfish.jpg
 Koala.jpg
```

then when you click on one, the code will run and insert your new picture in place of the old one. This should at least get you started, and you can tweak the code to suit your purposes. Make sure you have a picture in your worksheet, that is the size and position that you want, and then the new picture will be in the same place, and the same size.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out later and let you know. I appreciate the response.